# javascript, proper use of immediate function?

Tags: javascript, iife

When invoking a setter function of signature `fn(string, boolean)` does it make sense to use an immediate function to flip its current value?

```
Session.set('someBoolean', (function() {
  return !Session.get('someBoolean')
})())
```

This is the expression I was actually trying to construct

```
$('.nav-icon')
  .html(Session.get('navOpen') ? '←' : '<i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>)
```

Thank you guys, I was getting off track there.

Comment: I don't see the point of using a function here.

Comment: @azium. You should use `&larr;` html escape code instead of typing the left arrow character directly into your JS. http://www.escapecodes.info/ is a great resource for this type of thing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just:

```
Session.set('someBoolean', !Session.get('someBoolean'));
```